# Webpack 2 "exports is not defined"

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server, babeljs

I just updated to Webpack 2 and am receiving a runtime error `exports is not defined` in the browser. I changed my .babelrc from this:

```
{
  "plugins": [
    "syntax-flow",
    "transform-flow-strip-types",
    "add-module-exports"
  ],
  "presets": [
    "latest",
    "stage-2"
  ]
}
```

to this:

```
{
  "plugins": [
    "syntax-flow",
    "transform-flow-strip-types",
    "add-module-exports"
  ],
  "presets": [
    ["latest", {
        "es2015": {
            "modules": false
        }
    }],
    "stage-2"
  ]
}
```

To deactivate module import / export transpilation and leverage webpack 2's tree-shaking feature. Am I missing something? The build compiles correctly, but in the browser it just blows up.

Comment: I had a very similar problem and setting `modules: false` helped in my case. Is it possible that you are using an older version of some of the packages?

Comment: I'm on the latest versions of all my packages, and as you can see the `modules: false` is what is actually causing it ... using just the standard preset I get no errors. :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

TL;DR) Get rid of add-module-exports

To understand more about what's going on: https://ntucker.true.io/ntucker/webpack-2-uncaught-referenceerror-exports-is-not-defined/

Comment: Thanks, this was spot on.